# Flask-Babel: Is it possible to use two different translations of the same word?

Tags: flask, localization, internationalization, python-babel, flask-babel

I have the English word `Show`. In one part of the website, the word is used to mean a `theatrical performance`. But in another part of the website, the word is used to mean `to display`.

Is there a way I can create two different translations using the same word?